# Identifiers, initialization, and local variables in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, shader, fragment-shader

I'm having a bit of obscure trouble with ES shaders and I'm pretty much out of ideas by now.

Here's some code:

```
.. precision mediump float;
.. #define STEP (1f/6f)

53 vec4 colorBasedOnProgress(float progress){
54     float transition = (progress/STEP);   
55     transition = floor(transition);
56     float position = (progress - (transition*STEP)) * 7f;
57    
58     position = clamp(position, 0f, 1f);
59    
60     vec4 result;
61        
62     if(transition == 0f){
63         result = mix(COLOR_VIOLET, COLOR_BLUE, position);
64     } else if (transition == 1f){
65         result = mix(COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_GREEN, position);
66     } else if (transition == 2f){
67         result = mix(COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_YELLOW, position);
68     } else if (transition == 3f){
69         result = mix(COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_ORANGE, position);
70     } else if (transition == 4f){
71         result = mix(COLOR_ORANGE, COLOR_RED, position);
72     } else if (transition == 5f){
73         result = mix(COLOR_RED, COLOR_VIOLET, position);
74     }
75     
76     return result;
77 }
```

The errors I'm getting (just on the device, Galaxy S2):

```
09-16 00:05:04.415: I/InitialLoadingScreen(29901): 0:54: L0001: Expected token ')', found 'identifier'
09-16 00:05:04.415: I/InitialLoadingScreen(29901): 0:55: L0002: Undeclared variable 'transition'
09-16 00:05:04.415: I/InitialLoadingScreen(29901): 0:56: L0002: Undeclared variable 'transition'
09-16 00:05:04.415: I/InitialLoadingScreen(29901): 0:58: L0002: Undeclared variable 'position'
09-16 00:05:04.415: I/InitialLoadingScreen(29901): 0:62: L0002: Undeclared variable 'transition'
09-16 00:05:04.415: I/InitialLoadingScreen(29901): 0:64: L0001: Expected literal or '(', got 'else'
09-16 00:05:04.415: I/InitialLoadingScreen(29901): 0:66: L0001: Expected literal or '(', got 'else'
09-16 00:05:04.415: I/InitialLoadingScreen(29901): 0:68: L0001: Expected literal or '(', got 'else'
09-16 00:05:04.415: I/InitialLoadingScreen(29901): 0:70: L0001: Expected literal or '(', got 'else'
09-16 00:05:04.415: I/InitialLoadingScreen(29901): 0:72: L0001: Expected literal or '(', got 'else'
```

I don't have much experience with shader languages, so I'm not exactly sure where to begin tackling this. Any help and pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried compiling your code. The problem seems to be coming because of your use of floats, 1f,2f,3f etc

Instead try 1.,2.,3. This is how I always define floating points in my shader programs.
I compiled this with the Mali Shader compiler successfully. So it should work on the S2 since S2 has a Mali GPU in it.

Comment: That's was it! Thanks a lot! Thanks so much about pointing me to the Mali Shader compiler, looks really useful!

Comment: Also, I dug up the appropriate part of the language spec, the 1f notation is indeed illegal syntax [Chapter 4.1.4: Floats] :

floating-constant : fractional-constant [exponent-part] | digit-sequence exponent-part

fractional-constant : digit-sequence . digit-sequence |  digit-sequence . | . digit-sequence

I suspect that the Gallium drivers are using C-like shader compilers (I think they're based on LLVM) and they're picking it up as valid syntax.

Again, much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to be of help! Also the [Mali Development tools](http://www.malideveloper.com/developer-resources/tools/index.php) are quite handy. I find it better to run and check my code on the emulator, speeds up debugging and overall development